# How do I get the correct bounding box from GDAL corner coordinates?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, leaflet, gdal

I have a program that is grabbing the corner coordinates from a TIFF image and using those coordinates to get the lower left and upper right lat/lon values in decimal format.

Gdal outputs values in degrees, minutes, and seconds, so in my program, I am converting the lower left and upper right coordinates to lat/lon decimal values. The problem is that when I overlay the tiff on a map, the dimensions of the overlay are incorrect, which leads me to believe that I am calculating the bounding box incorrectly.

Here is the gdal output:

```
Upper Left  (  681480.000, 1913050.000) ( 87d39'59.59"W, 41d55' 1.56"N)
Lower Left  (  681480.000, 1882578.800) ( 87d40' 2.72"W, 41d50' 0.54"N)
Upper Right (  704407.200, 1913050.000) ( 87d34'56.36"W, 41d54'59.69"N)
Lower Right (  704407.200, 1882578.800) ( 87d34'59.88"W, 41d49'58.67"N)
Center      (  692943.600, 1897814.400) ( 87d37'29.64"W, 41d52'30.14"N)
```

And here are my bounding box coordinates:
(southwest lat,lon) (northeast lat,lon)
41.000,-87.001,41.017,-87.016

How do I correctly calculate the bounding box values? I am using leaflet to overlay the image, and it expects a southwest point and a northeast point.